# Convert words to binary values

Tags: c, string, binary

I need to convert **words** to **binary** numbers, positioned vertically (\n).
I need to write a function, which will do this convert.. Below is a sample..
*Can you help me please?*

```
//main
char* text = "Hello, how are you?";
const int len = strlen(text);
bool bytes1[len+1][8];
encode_string(text, bytes1);
for(int j = 0; j <= len; j++){
    printf("%c: ", text[j]);
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        printf("%d", bytes1[j][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
// prints:
// H: 01001000
// e: 01100101
// l: 01101100
// l: 01101100
// o: 01101111
// ,: 00101100
//  : 00100000
// h: 01101000
// o: 01101111
// w: 01110111
//  : 00100000
// a: 01100001
// r: 01110010
// e: 01100101
//  : 00100000
// y: 01111001
// o: 01101111
// u: 01110101
// ?: 00111111
// : 00000000

//function
void encode_string(const char string[], bool bytes[strlen(string)+1][8]){

}
```

Comment: What about your code does not work?

Comment: Regarding comments in previous answer below:  "_Ok but programs will be working with this sample (in main injected):..., and I have these errors"_.  I suggest doing some of the work yourself..., and get a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy man you can use this:

Converting every char:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void){

    char* text = "Hello, how are you?";
    int len_size = strlen(text);

    for(int j = 0; j <= len_size; j++){
        printf("%c: ", text[j]);
        for( int i = 7; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            printf( "%d", ( text[j] >> i ) & 1 ? 1 : 0 );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Onother option with your function:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

void encode_string(char string[], int len_size);

int main(void){

    char* text = "Hello, how are you?";
    int len_size = strlen(text);
    encode_string(text, len_size);
    return 0;
}

void encode_string(char string[], int len_size){
    for(int j = 0; j <= len_size; j++){
        printf("%c: ", string[j]);
        for( int i = 7; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            printf( "%d", ( string[j] >> i ) & 1 ? 1 : 0 );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

[image]

I know your error already, your are trying to send to the function, and you dont send the right parameters...

Comment: @OnlyForFun Its working for me, I will index a print

Comment: @OnlyForFun Your are trying so assign a function `mblen` and you dont want that so, use the size of string! It will work, then mark the question with green check so people dont lose more time with this question solved

Comment: i have copied your code and I have this 1 error, look below: 


`qr.c: In function ‘encode_string’:
qr.c:76:21: error: ‘len’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘mblen’?
   76 | for(int j = 0; j <= len; j++){
      |                     ^~~
      |                     mblen
qr.c:76:21: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears`

screen: https://ibb.co/n3yFk4m

Comment: @OnlyForFun Have you declared it correctly send a print of your code! Like you did from your shell

Comment: @OnlyForFun Or if you want you cand send all your code to here: https://codeshare.io and click share, then send me the link, I will fix that! I think that is a stupid problem, maybe a bad declaration of a function/variable.